# Android device compatibility issue

Tags: android, google-play

How can I review why these phones in the picture below not support with my application.

and what is different between Samsung Galaxy Tab4 7.0 which were highlighted.

Does anyone know this?

[image]

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:maxSdkVersion="23"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23"
        />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.xxx.xxx.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

<permission android:name="com.xxx.xxx.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>

<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true"
        />

<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false"
        />
```

Comment: @MuhammadBabar as your requested

Comment: thanks manifest looks fine. Wonder if the disabled devices doesn't have camera + opegles 0x2!